ICryptoTransform Padding is invalid and cannot be removed after a while
I'm using this function to decrypt files in a windows service. After a few days it suddenly start to give this error:
---Exception---
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

---StackTrace---
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at MySalesWorks.SendMail.DecryptContents(Stream stream, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv, String fileName)

This is the function:
Public Shared Function DecryptContents(stream As Stream, key() As Byte, iv() As Byte, fileName As String) As MemoryStream
    Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim logger As PerformanceLogger = clsMain.CreatePerformanceLogger()
    Try
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Information, stream.Length.ToString)
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Information, iv.Length.ToString)
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Information, fileName)
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Information, PaddingMode.PKCS7.ToString)
        Using aes As New AesManaged() With {.Key = key, .IV = iv, .Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7}
            Using tempStream As New MemoryStream()
                Using aesDecryptor As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor()
                    Using cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(stream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                        cryptoStream.CopyTo(tempStream)
                        cryptoStream.Flush()
                        tempStream.Seek(SeekOrigin.Begin, 0)
                        tempStream.CopyTo(memStream)
                        tempStream.Flush()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Error, "Done")
        memStream.Seek(SeekOrigin.Begin, 0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Log(ex)
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Error, fileName)
        logger.Log(EventLogEntryType.Error, ex.InnerException)
    End Try

    Return memStream
End Function

I'm running the same service on another server where there are no issues. Why is this error coming up after a few days and what can I do?
Decrypt files (pdf's and images)
